# How can i check my device is connected with internet or not in android?

Tags: android

**Explanation:**
           Hello Everyone, I am trying to check my device is connected with internet or not. I am explaining all the step what i do.

**Step-1:** I have created a receiver class to check when the connection status change.

**Step-2:** I also created a Interface in which i have method to get the connection status (true/false)

**Step-3:** Implement this listener on my Activity and then override the listener method.

**Step-4:** If my internet is connected then go ahead. If my internet is not connected i put the message your internet is not connected.

**Step-5:** Finally i register this receiver in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Note: All above step is working fine until SDK_VERSION Marshmallow. When i checked it with Nougt(7.0) then it's not working.

**Receiver**

```
public class ConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static ConnectivityReceiverListener connectivityReceiverListener;

    public ConnectivityReceiver(){
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (connectivityReceiverListener != null) {
            connectivityReceiverListener.onNetworkConnectionChanged(Utils.isInternetConnected(context));
        }
    }
    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        if(Utils.isInternetConnected(context)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
public interface ConnectivityReceiverListener {
    void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected);
}
```

**Internet connection status method**

```
public static boolean isInternetConnected(final Context _context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) _context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null) {
            if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI) {
                return true;
            } else if (activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE) {
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Permission and register receiver in Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<receiver
            android:name="com.durian.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver"
            android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

**Below method is check internet connetion**

```
private boolean checkConnection() {
    boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected(CustomerActivity.this);
    showSnack(isConnected);
    return isConnected;
}
```

**Below method is check isconnected or not**

```
private void showSnack(boolean isConnected) {
    String message;
    int color;
    Snackbar snackbar;
    if (isConnected) {
        Toast.make(getActivity(),"CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.make(getActivity(),"Disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**Below method call the listener**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AppController.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
}
```

Here is my Application class which register in android with name parameter

```
public class AppController extends Application{

    public static final String TAG=AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    public static Typeface fntGabriola;
    public static Typeface fntRalewayLight;
    public static Typeface fntRalewayMedium;
    public static Typeface fntRalewayRegular;
    public static Typeface fntRalewaySemiBold;
    public static Typeface fntsegoeuRegular;
    public static Typeface fntsegoeuLight;
    public static Typeface fntsegoeSemiBold;
    public static Typeface fntModerneSans;
    public static Typeface fntMordernist;
    public static Typeface fntOpenSans;

    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        fntGabriola=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Gabriola.ttf");
        fntRalewayLight=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf");
        fntRalewayMedium=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Medium.ttf");
        fntRalewayRegular=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf");
        fntRalewaySemiBold=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Raleway-SemiBold.ttf");
        fntsegoeuRegular=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/segoeui.ttf");
        fntsegoeuLight=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/segoeuil.ttf");
        fntsegoeSemiBold=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/seguisb.ttf");
        fntModerneSans=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/moderne_sans.ttf");
        fntMordernist=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Sk-Modernist-Regular.otf");
        fntOpenSans=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf");
    }
    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public void setConnectivityListener(ConnectivityReceiverListener listener) {
        ConnectivityReceiver.connectivityReceiverListener = listener;
    }
}
```

Note: Everything is working fine below the **nought** OS Version. But the problem is when i test in **nought** it is not working. Please give a proper solutions which working in all the OS.

**For reference you can check the snapdeal application**

I want exactly as in snapdeal Android application.

Comment: Does your app depend on any REST endpoints?

Comment: Yes it totally depends on the REST.

Comment: I think you should check each web service separately.

Comment: I don't want to check API i only want to check is my application is connected with internet or not. Forget about the API and all that.

Comment: Might be a permission problem. For newest android versions you must declare permission in manifest and request it at runtime too. Here the offical  guide - [link](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Comment: @GiacomoLai i also check at runtime permission. There is no run time permission for the internet and Access_network State.

Comment: Could you please refer this link to get better idea What i want.

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: What I had in mind was that in reality you probably only care about the internet because you plan on using it.  Just deal with the problem when it happens, which could be at any point in your app, for any websevice.

Comment: If you verify that the internet is working, but then 5 minutes later a user's data drops off, you still need to cover that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**You can simply use below code Snippet**/

/**Below code Check 2 condition that Your device is connected to Wifi or Data - Connection or not. If yes then will also check that Internet is working or not..**/

/**ConnectivityReceiver Class**/

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class ConnectivityReceiver
{
   private static ConnectivityReceiver.AsyncResponse asyncResponse;

/************************************************    for checking internet connection*******/
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context)
{

    ConnectivityManager connectivity = null;
    boolean isNetworkAvail = false;
    try
    {
        connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if (connectivity != null)
        {
            connectivity = null;
        }
    }
    return isNetworkAvail;
}

private static class ConnectionCheck extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>
{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params)
    {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try
        {
            if(params[0].endsWith("") || params[0] == null)
            {
                params[0] = "http://www.google.com/";
            }

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            if (!url.getHost().equals(urlConnection.getURL().getHost()))
            {
                // we were redirected! Kick the user out to the browser to sign on?

                return true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

            return false;
        }
        finally
        {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        asyncResponse.processFinish(aBoolean);

    }
}


public interface AsyncResponse
{
    void processFinish(boolean output);
}
public static void speedTest(String url,ConnectivityReceiver.AsyncResponse asyncResponse)
{
    ConnectivityReceiver.asyncResponse = asyncResponse;
    new ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectionCheck().execute(url);
}
 }


/**Code implementation in your class**/

String ConnectionCheck_Url = "http://www.google.com/";

if(ConnectivityReceiver.isNetworkAvailable(MainActivity.this))
    {
        ConnectivityReceiver.speedTest(ConnectionCheck_Url,new ConnectivityReceiver.AsyncResponse()
        {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(boolean output)
            {
                if (output)
                {

                    /* * If The output Value --->"True" Then Only 
              request will Execute
                     * NOTE: Here "True" Value Means Intenet is Working*/

                    // Implement your code here
                }
                else
                {
                   //Please_Check_Your_Internet_Connection
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else
    {
      //  Please_Connect_to_your_Wifi_or_Data_Connection
    }
}

/**Android MainifestFile.xml**/

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```